# Can't use sudo when autologin in Arch Linux

Tags: automation, arch-linux, sudo, arm, tty

I have a Pandaboard running Arch Linux, the default non root user is alarm. I'm trying to automatically login at startup with the alarm user. I followed the instructions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Automatic_login_to_virtual_console) and created the file `/etc/systemd/system/serial-getty@ttyO2.service.d/autologin.conf` with the following content:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/agetty --autologin alarm -s %I 115200,38400,9600 vt102
```

I'm logged in automatically as expected but when I try to run some command with sudo, I enter the password and when I press the Enter key nothing happens, I have to kill sudo with Ctrl+C, the same happens when running `sudo -s`. I can autologin as root user replacing `alarm` by `root` but I don't want to execute all the commands as superuser. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Could you `strace -p $(pgrep sudo)` to see where it hangs?

Comment: @Tobu I need `sudo` to run `strace -p $(pgrep sudo)` :/